# If data gets updated in the db within catch time how to handle in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I am using hibernate second level cache mechanism (ehcache). I gave 10 seconds as cache time like below

```
<cache name="employee" maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="10" timeToLiveSeconds="10">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
</cache>
```

If suppose the data in the db gets updated within that 10 seconds cache time will I get the latest data or the catch data? How to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a cache with a *time-to-live* and *time-to-idle* configured, the entry will stay valid in the cache as long as it is accessed at least once every 10 seconds.

Given the situation you describe, I strongly recommend against the use of TTI because of that.

As for the more generic answer: the moment you activate caching you open up a window of inconsistency. If your application logic cannot cope with it, you need to put in place an immediate invalidation mechanism that will flush entries from the cache eagerly.

However there is no standard way of doing that and thus it becomes your responsibility.